# Why firefox do not show actual information from server after page reload?

Tags: javascript, php, firefox, server, delay

I have made small web-app: http://letme.ijn.su

At this moment I debug it on PC.
I have problems with Firefox - when I make some changes on server side(add more notes) and resfresh page - I see changes only after some time. Other browsers(chrome, opera, yandex) work well


I suppose it is because of firefox cashing - how can I force it to get new info from server with every request?


I use Ubuntu, Apache, PHP.
by link http://letme.ijn.su - you launch index.php, which print job-page or login-page(have you cookies or not).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force the browser to reload cached CSS/JS files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118884/how-to-force-the-browser-to-reload-cached-css-js-files)

Comment: still trying...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will work `clearstatcache();` This should clear the cache on the server side. Or if you want to delete a file you can use `unlink();`

Answer (score 0):

I think clearing your browser cache will work best. Also, make sure to check the "Disable Cache" is the inspector settings. You can also try "View Page Source" in Firefox and refresh the newly-opened tab containing the page source.

Comment: ))))) Look boiski answer